# PhoneGap Templates Installed in XCode 4

Tags: cordova, xcode4

I have installed PhoneGap, but I have the beta release of xcode4 installed on my machine with the older release version 3.2

when i installed PhoneGap, the Template went to the old version not XCode4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the author of the PhoneGap installer. PhoneGap will not support Xcode 4 yet, until it's of beta quality. I would just copy it over to where it would be for now.

Comment: This is why: https://devforums.apple.com/message/272958 (need Apple Dev Program Login)

Comment: xcode4 is no more in beta, but I still cannot find the templates.

Comment: not implemented yet, it's planned: http://phonegap.lighthouseapp.com/projects/20116/tickets/120

Comment: We've migrated from Lighthouse to Github - new location for the issue is https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/issues/42

Answer (score 2):

Now XCode is out of beta (4.0.1 currently) and still you can't create Phonegap project. If you have to create a new project for Phonegap using XCode 4 use the [command line script here](http://www.phonegap.com/2011/03/16/creating-a-phonegap-project-from-the-command-line-for-xcode-4/):

Phonegap works with Xcode 4 it's just the templates that doesn't work and you can't create a new project directly in XCode

Comment: Thanks for the link to the script. The [PhoneGap quick start page] for iOS doesn't say anything about a particular version of Xcode being required, so I was surprised that it didn't work with Xcode 4.

Comment: In the interim, you can generate a PhoneGap template from here: http://build.phonegap.com/generate

Answer (score 1):

I'd help you, but XCode 4 is under NDA.

**coughs* the templates directory is laid out differently *coughs**

Answer (score -1):

There's a phonegap xcode 4 template beta. There are some issues but I got it to work:
http://blogs.nitobi.com/shazron/2011/05/05/phonegap-xcode-4-template/

Remember the following (taken from the installation program):
On first run, it will create a sample "www" folder for you inside your project. After that, you MUST drag and drop the "www" folder into your project in Xcode, to create a folder reference for it.